# An example of $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}_p$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I want to know an example of $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}_p$.

$\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $K$ is defined as galois extension over $K$ whose galois group is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_p$ as an abelian group.

In the case $K＝\Bbb{Q}$, $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension is uniquely determined and which is called cyclotomic $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension.

But what about in the case of $K＝\Bbb{Q}_p$?
Is there $\Bbb{Z}_p$-extension over $\Bbb{Q}_p$ ?

Comment: Well, have you tried to imitate the idea of the cyclotomic $\mathbb Z_p$-extension? What obstacles (if any) do you see when doing it over $\mathbb Q_p$ instead of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: If we could find the field $K_n/ \Bbb{Q}$ whose galois group is isom to $Z/p^nZ$, taking inverse limit solve the problem. Such $K_n$ can be found by fundamental theorem of cyclotomic extension and fundamental theorem of cyclic group in the case of $ \Bbb{Q}$, but in the case of $ \Bbb{Q}_p$, alternative method 'Lubin tate extension' does not give such $K_n$, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Do you know what the Galois group of the cyclotomic field extension $\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^n}) \vert \mathbb Q_p$ is (with $\zeta_{p^n}$ a primitive $p^n$-th root of unity)?

Comment: it is isom to $(Z/p^nZ)^×$, oh, then, when $p$ is odd prime, it is cyclic group of order $p^{n-1}(p-1)$. Exchanging $n$ to $n +1$, we gain $K_n/ \Bbb{Q}_p$ which is isom to $Z/p^nZ$, so the completely same argument works. Lubin tate extension appears in the case we exchange $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ to general local field.

Comment: Note that there is also an *unramified* $\mathbb Z_p$-extension, which follows quickly from the fact that for any $n$, there is a unique unramified extension of degree $n$, and that one's cyclic. Now just look at the $n$ which are $p$-powers.

Comment: $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^\infty})$ and 

$\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{p^{p^\infty}-1})$ are two examples. Exercice: are there more?

Answer (score 2):

One can easily generalize the construction of the cyclotomic $\mathbb Z_p$-extension over $\mathbb Q_p$. This is the case the local field $\mathbb Q_p$ does not interfer with $p$-th power roots of unity (the only *new* roots of unity are the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity by Hensel's lemma).

Indeed, the extensions $K_n=\mathbb Q_p(\zeta_{p^n})$ are still Galois extension with groups $(\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z)^\ast$. A case distinction for $p=2$ and $p\ne2$ yields a sequence of compatible extension fields with Galois groups $\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, hence a $\mathbb Z_p$-extension of $\mathbb Q_p$ by the general theory of infinite Galois groups.